# What kind of rhetorical strategy is it when someone points out a potential sticking point in his proposition before anyone can criticize it?

Tags: single-word-requests, figures-of-speech

E.g.:

- > I know some of you might consider this question general reference, but think of all those people who will be reading it all over the world and how it will enrich our data bank.
- > Of course we all know how expensive it would be to build new headquarters for our institute. But think of what is going to happen to our research center and our reputation if we don't

Edit - changed "fallacy" to "rhetorical strategy"

Comment: This is not a fallacy. This is a rhetorical strategy, and a very successful and common one. It has nothing to do with logic, only presentation.

Comment: How about replacing 'flaw' here with 'potential sticking point'? Surely nobody points out what's wrong with his argument. He should rethink it. He's pointing out where differences of opinion about policy are likely to occur.

Comment: It is not a fallacy. It is a strategy. A preemptive strategy. A preemptive reflexive strategy - to first point out the perceived weakness and in reflex use its mitigation as a magnet to coagulate the effectiveness of your strategy.

Comment: What kind of fallacy did the asker make here by assuming it's a fallacy, when it's only a strategy whose argument might *contain* a fallacy?

Comment: @BlessedGeek, your “magnet to coagulate effectiveness” phrase is absurd.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good call.

Comment: I was taught to call this the "yes, but" clause. The purpose is to address potential problems within your argument and address them before anyone even sees them. As was mentioned, it can be a very effective addition to an already solid argument. So in use you say "Yes, viking hats might be dumb, but they are really going to make us look badass."

Comment: See also, "in before" or [INB4](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=inb4)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's not a logical fallacy. It's a very common rhetorical tactic called [*procatalepsis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procatalepsis), or more colloquially in American English, [*prebuttal*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prebuttal).

The strategy consists of anticipating your opponent's argument, and then responding to it, as if they had raised the objection themselves. That way, they can't later raise that objection, because you've already done it for them and explained why that line of thinking would be wrong.

Of course, the *way* in which you respond to the argument may contain a logical fallacy, but that's a separate issue from the fact that the rhetorical strategy is being used at all.

Comment: But if there is a flaw in your argument, you **can't** explain why your opponent's [expected] argument will be wrong. Procatalepsis seems to refer to a successful pre-emptive counter to an expected counter-argument, not a prior admission of the inadequacy of one's own.

Comment: Rhetorically speaking, it's only a flaw if someone applies the critical thinking necessary to determine that this is true. Otherwise, it may seem like a very reasonable thing to say and be quite persuasive to the audience. That's why logical fallacies aren't always obvious to observers.

Comment: The definitions I can find say that procatalepsis is an _attempt_ to respond pre-emptively to expected arguments. It doesn't have to be a valid or successful response, any more than it would be if the response were made after the objection.

Comment: ... Sounds like orcish mischief to me. Politics. OK, I'll leave logic behind for a few moments (in any case, OP's examples are hardly black and white).

Comment: @Barmar That makes it the correct answer, and highly useful (if only a few more people knew the word).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I agree that it's the correct answer, I upvoted it. I was responding to your "flaw" argument against it, but I forgot to address it properly.

Comment: @Barmar An obvious lack of flaw polish.

Comment: @Barmar The problem, I'm sure after re-reading, is with the title here. Replacing 'flaw' with 'weak point' or similar makes quite a difference. One needs addressing and correcting, to make the argument valid (ie the problem is with the speaker); the other needs discussing and evaluating, and then people can weigh up the pros and cons (ie the problem is real-world).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see your point. Perhaps what the OP meant is _supposed flaw_. On the other hand, a flaw doesn't have to be a fatal flaw, it can be something you can live with, and the procatalepsis tries to explain that the benefits overcome it.

Comment: Yes. I'm saying that the answer is right, but the question ...

Comment: In debate this is often called a block.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd like to note that the presence of a logical fallacy does *not* necessarily indicate a false statement or incorrect position - merely that the logic used to defend the statement or position is faulty.  I could, for example, argue that 2+2=4 *because it is right*, and that would be a fallacy *despite* the truth of the original statement.

Comment: @Zibbobz: Right. But you probably shouldn't be _persuaded_ by the speaker. (For example, if you wrongly believed that 2 + 2 = 5, it might be even _more_ wrong to be convinced that 2 + 2 = 4 by virtue of a fallacious argument.)

Comment: @Zibbobz: But I was pointing out that OP's '[a] flaw in his proposition [here surely = proposal]' would be taken by most English speakers to mean 'something wrong with what he's saying' not 'a real problem we'll meet in trying to implement what he's suggesting'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  A friendly discussion like this is always useful for everyone. As for my use of "flaw", I see what you mean. "Sticking point" is exactly what I mean. In the second example, the person knows that building new headquarters will "swallow" most of the annual budget but it is his interest that it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a fallacy. But you could call the rhetorical technique a [stratagem](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stratagem).

> an artifice or trick in war for deceiving and outwitting the enemy
>
> skill in ruses or trickery

Dale Carnegie proffered this stratagem in [How to Win Friends and Influence People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Win_Friends_and_Influence_People).

In "Be a Leader," points 8 and 9 are:

- Use encouragement. Make the fault seem easy to correct.
- Make the other person happy about doing what you suggest.

Carnegie suggests for the eighth point that you surface a flaw in your own proposal that is easy for the hearer to correct. When the hearer recognizes the easy solution, he begins to have some emotional connection to the idea. He begins to embrace your idea as his own idea, and then (in the ninth point) is happy to do what you suggest.

Comment: You could call it a "statement" and a "sentence" too.   Each of these would be true, but don't really provide the meaning asked for in the question.   "strategem" is not "a kind of strategy where you point out the fallacy before anyone else can".   "strategem" is any kind of strategy....

Comment: Please take a look at the definition of *stratagem*, listed in the answer. *Stratagem* is *not* any kind of strategy. *Stratagem* contains the sense of a trick or a ruse. Torpedoing your own proposal in order to promote it has the feel of a ruse.